# Get ImageView width in getView

Tags: android, listview, imageview, listadapter, getview

I can't get the width of an ImageView in my ListAdapter's getView method...

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoPost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

In my ListAdapter's getView...

```
holder.photoPost = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoPost);
int targetHeight = holder.photoPost.getWidth() * (9/16);
```

I'm toasting the targetHeight and it's always 0 which means the getWidth() method is returning 0. I've tried many different things. Please help!

Comment: Regarding to the android documentation ` android:visibility:gone` set the view to doesn't take any layout space. Just a suggestion:try using invisible instead of gone.

Comment: Please give feedback if it works

Comment: invisible and visible both did not work.

Comment: You ImageView matches the width of parent. Why you don't get the width of the parent as it is the same of the child imageview. You are providing not much information so it's difficult to help xou

Comment: ah ok good point I'll try that

Comment: Maybe you're trying to use the width before it was set? Try to put your Toast in OnLayoutChangeListener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#addOnLayoutChangeListener(android.view.View.OnLayoutChangeListener)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you try to `getWidth`, your `ImageView` have not been appeared on the screen, so it always returns 0. So there are two ways, you can get the width:

***First way***

You need to `measure` your `ImageView` and then get the `measuredWidth`:

```
holder.photoPost = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoPost);
holder.photoPost.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

int targetHeight = holder.photoPost.getMeasuredWidth() * (9/16);
```

***Second way***

Add `onGlobalLayoutListener` to your `ImageView` and then, you will be able to get the width:

```
holder.photoPost = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoPost);
holder.photoPost.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                holder.photoPost.getViewTreeObserver()
                        .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                holder.photoPost.getViewTreeObserver()
                        .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            int targetHeight = holder.photoPost.getWidth() * (9/16)
        }
});
```

Comment: First way resulted in 0

Comment: Why multiply with (9/16) ?

Comment: Don't know, the author of the question has needed that ratio.

Comment: I think it should be :
int targetHeight = ( holder.photoPost.getMeasuredWidth() *9)/16;